# Detection over only some chosen frequency bins

Tags: signal-processing, fft

In Periodogram Can I take only few frequency bins (nFFT bins) , sum and compare  it with threshold in stead of whole bins . if yes why?

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Using just a few bins of a FFT magnitude might be equivalent to using a bandpass filter (or filters) on a rectangular window of data, and summing the energy output.  Various forms of a Goertzel filter or algorithm are also equivalent to computing 1 bin of a DFT.